# HNT-Solana migration issues

Tags: migration, solana

Yes I used the migration tool hnt to solana but I didn’t get my conversion 65 hnt to sol I used the website and everything. I wasn’t able to swap them before on the helium app due to signing errors. Has anyone has this issue in the past and if so how do you resolve it?